# Does an amplifier consume any power when nothing is connected? (GPD2846A built-in 2W amplifier)

Tags: amplifier, sd, power-consumption, mp3, player

The GPD2846A module has a built-in amplifier into it. However, I want to use it with my headphones which don't require 1-2W *(they are definitely going to distort sound and possibly be damaged)*. So I thought I could just solder the DAC-L, DAC-R pins *(audio Left and Right output pins)* and GND to a headphone jack and call it a day.

My concern is whether the amplifier wastes the 1-2W of power it normally would with a speaker connected *(small form factor is desired so the battery is small and every mAh counts)* even if there is nothing connected to it. I suppose if yes, I'll need to un-solder it from the board but I'd like to keep it there for future improvements so have that in mind too when answering please :)

Comment: There's more than one way to design an amplifier, and some designs can be _much_ more efficient than certain other designs. That module is so cheap, why not buy a few of them to play with, and measure the power consumption yourself?

Answer (score 3):

"Does it consume any power": Yes.

"Does it consume the 1-2 W it would with a speaker connected": No.

It'll pull a tiny bit of power, though it's impossible to know how much without the datasheet for the amplifier. It won't consume significant amounts of power unless it's actually driving an output.

---

I doubt connecting your headphones directly to the DAC output will work very well, by the way. Couldn't say for yours in particular, but DACs aren't usually designed to drive a load directly.

Comment: what does "designed to drive a load directly" entail?

Comment: @user253751 Sufficiently low output impedance.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do to drive headphones? The first solution that comes to mind is a resistor but that would waste huge amounts of energy.

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΘ No, a resistor would make it worse. You need an amplifier.

Comment: So I should swap the 2W amp for a headphone amplifier? I'd like to have both headphone and speaker output so maybe solder them in parallel with a switch to shift from headphone to speaker amp?

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΘ That would work. You can get 3.5 mm headphone jacks that have a switch built in that would let you automatically switch when you plug in headphones, too.